# How does one add <graphics.h> into GCC on a Windows computer for C?

Tags: c, windows, powershell, gcc

So, I want to add graphics in a program, but <graphics.h> doesn't seem to be supported on the GCC compiler.
I don't have a Linux, so please include Windows Powershell solutions if using command lines for the solution.
I am using the C programming language.
Since I can't find a good solution online by searching for it on Google, GeeksForGeeks, or stackoverflow, I am looking for it by asking this question.

I am not asking how to do in C++, **in C**!

I was expecting to have no issues, but the GCC compiler couldn't find `<graphics.h>`.

I hope someone can find a solution!

Comment: You simply don't use ancient MS DOS graphics libraries in Windows. Because people stopped using MS DOS over 20 years ago. Why do you want to learn how to become a MS DOS programmer?

Comment: Then what do you suggest using instead? @Lundin

Comment: @Tworsfeline: See the duplicate question in order to get suggestions for alternatives. Most of the information in the duplicate question also applies to C, since `grahics.h` is a C API (which can be used in both C and C++).

Comment: Are you looking for an API as similar as possible to the old `graphics.h` API? Or are you just looking for any good API with which you can draw 2D graphics?